# how get the value of the closest td using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to get value of the closest  using class name.

```
var remaningHoursValue = $(this).closest('td').find('.remainingHours');
```

I getting the value using id but by using class name i am not able to get result properly. result is [object, object]. From this result how to get the value in td.

Comment: _"result is [object, object]"_ jQuery methods return jQuery _objects_. Don't `alert` the result, use `console.log()` for debugging.

Comment: actually i am very new with Jquery. If it is possible for you to give me an example then please post it.

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
$(this).closest('td.remainingHours');
```

your selector, finds the closest `td` element and searches for an element with class `remainingHours` inside it

Comment: when i am using alert i am still getting result as [object, object].

Comment: @AnuRaj try `alert($(this).closest('td.remainingHours').text())`

Comment: @AnuRaj then try `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').closest('td.remainingHours');
```

for text of the element

```
 $('*').closest('td.remainingHours').text();
```

for log and alert()

```
  alert($('*').closest('td.remainingHours').text());
```